# Listing blog post excerpts

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created many sites that requires [php](/questions/tagged/php) and [html](/questions/tagged/html). They all work fine, but I'm now thinking if all that time I do it in a wrong way. 
Usually, first I build the site template, then styling and last I code php. 
Then I just include the php functions etc in the HTML. 
For example take a look of a table that lists some posts (index.php):

```
        <div class="posts">
            <h1 class="content-title">New Posts</h1>
            <?php
                $rows = list_posts();
                while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($rows)) {
                    echo "                                  
                        <div>
                            <img class='post-avatar' src='img/icon_newsletter.jpg'>
                            <h2 class='post-title'>".$row['post_title']."</h2>
                            <p class='post-meta'>
                                Από <a href='#'>".$row['post_user']."</a> | ".$row['post_date']." | <a class='post-views' href='viewpost.php?id=".$row['post_id']."#comments'>Comments: ".total_comments($row['post_id'])."</a>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                ".substr($row['post_body'], 0, 180)."...
                            </p>
                            <img class='post-icon-read' src='img/read.png' /> <a href='viewpost.php?id=".$row['post_id']."'>Read More..</a>
                       </div>               
                    "; 
                }
            ?>      
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do consider it a bad practice outputting markups using `echo`. It's very hard to maintain since it will likely affect the indention making it too far from left. Also one important thing is that you don't have to worry about escaping your string.

e.g.

```
<?php 
  echo "<span>"Yes," she said, "I would love some tea."</span>";
?>
```

This line will give you a `parse: syntax error`

Then you would do to fix that by doing :

```
<?php
  echo "<span>\"Yes,\" she said, \"I would love some tea.\"</span>";
?>
```

Which could be bothersome and it's an eyesore.

So how I write markups with the `PHP` given in your example

```
<?php $rows = list_posts(); ?>
<?php while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($rows)) : ?>
 <div>
  <img class='post-avatar' src='img/icon_newsletter.jpg'>
  <h2 class='post-title'><?php echo $row['post_title']; ?></h2>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

You can use [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for a cleaner code